# extra (unwanted) space between grids

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and trying to have a nested grid page,

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  grid: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    height: 100
  }
});

function CenteredGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid container item xs={9}>
          <Grid className={classes.grid} item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid className={classes.grid} item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

CenteredGrid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CenteredGrid);
```

below is what I get from the code.
I noted that when the right side component (which has the word test inside it) gets longer, the left side bottom component goes down in a way that it's in the middle of the space that it has, but what I need is having those two left side grids to be under each other WITHOUT the gap. Please, could you tell 
EDITED:
1) why is this happening?
2) also noted if I remove the `container` from the inner Grid the gap is gone, why is it causing the gap?
3) please if you have any other solution tell me exactly why they are working and the doc (the exact page not a whole website please) where I can go and learn them

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a style attribute of `display: table` to the outer `Grid` container and a `display: inline-flex` on the `Grid` inner-containers:

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/1rwnr1y433

**Grid.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  grid: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    height: 100
  }
});

function CenteredGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid style={{ display: "table" }} container spacing={24}>
        <Grid style={{ display: "inline-flex" }} container item xs={9}>
          <Grid className={classes.grid} item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid className={classes.grid} item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid style={{ display: "inline-flex" }} item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
            teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

CenteredGrid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CenteredGrid);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me where on the Material UI website you got this information? i mean that `display: table`  and  `display: inline-flex`

Comment: No docs. Just my brain. :) You can, however, utilize/browse this website for all things CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: i edited my question, could you please change your answer for that, thanks indeed